# Is there a website that tells me the quickest way between two London Tube stations?

Tags: public-transport, online-resources, london

I understand that [the tube map](http://www.bbc.co.uk/london/travel/downloads/tube_map.gif) isn't geographically accurate and that there's [several](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/25522/1264) [examples](http://www.timeout.com/london/things-to-do/londons-shortest-tube-journey-1) where walking is quicker than catching the tube, even in non-obvious scenarios.

Is there a website that, when I put in two tube stations, lets me know which is the quickest way between the two of them - walking or tube?

Comment: There'a an Android app for it https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.visualit.tubeLondonCity I assume there are iPhone equivalents. Veyr handy to have

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes there is: **[Google Maps](http://maps.google.com/)**, specifically the ["new" version](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3092426?hl=en), which offers sensible alternatives automatically.  For example, if you enter a query like "[King's Cross station to Euston Station](https://www.google.com.au/maps/dir/King%27s+Cross+station,+Euston+Rd,+London+N1+9AP,+United+Kingdom/Euston+Station,+Euston+Rd,+London+NW1+2RT,+United+Kingdom/@51.5281611,-0.1333415,16z/data=!3m2!4b1!5s0x48761b2435e648fb:0x6730f3e38386d53b!4m13!4m12!1m5!1m1!1s0x48761b3955899dd1:0x6adfd2969b4f9656!2m2!1d-0.123451!2d51.530693!1m5!1m1!1s0x48761b23f9215735:0xa5428a5c064ffdaa!2m2!1d-0.133624!2d51.528006)", it will tell you that you can take the Tube (every 2 min, estimated time 6 min) *and* that you could just walk it (estimated time 11 min).

Comment: Does it include travel time within the station? Especially since the most recent redevelopment, there's an awful lot of walking from the front door to the platform edge.

Comment: I believe so, at least approximately, although the example above starts from a central point within the station.  If you enter addresses nearby, it should account for the full time needed from the front door.

Comment: Google Maps usually works pretty darn well in other places as well. Eg. Japan. In Japan it'll tell you the cost of travel as well, so you can plan your trip accordingly.

Comment: Google maps is very accurate in my experience. Most people walk at a similar pace. The bike estimations are a bit more variable though. They can really only go by an average I suppose.

Comment: It's usually very good, but it gets the st pancras to euston route wrong by not using the midland road exit from st pancras.

Answer (score 22):

The official site is [TFL's Journey Planner](https://www.tfl.gov.uk/plan-a-journey/), and is quite flexible and descriptive:

[image]

[(source)](http://londonconnections.blogspot.com.au/2007/12/tfl-journey-planner-langdon-park-opens.html)

It's also possible to use [National Rail's site](http://nationalrail.co.uk/), depending on where you're going (I used to prefer this site when in London as it shows trains too, not just tube), and of course as jpatokal mentioned, [Google Maps](http://maps.google.com) handles it as well.

Comment: +1 For TfL's journey planner, but No No No! to using National Rail within London! National Rail has no clue how long tube journeys take, or transfer times or walking times... Use National Rail to get to London, TfL to get around London.

Comment: @AndyT shrug, I lived there for 4 years and it always seemed pretty good to me.  TFL is the true source though, of course.

Answer (score 11):

I’ve had good experiences with [**Citymapper**](https://citymapper.com/london/superrouter?) for getting around London.

(It also covers New York, Paris, Berlin, Washington DC and Boston, and they keep adding new cities.)

You can tell it which two places you want to travel between, and it shows you a variety of routes, including buses, walking, National Rail and of course the Underground. It includes rough timing, prices and nicely annotated maps to boot.

[image]

They also have [apps for iOS and Android](https://citymapper.com/apps/), which have worked well for me.

(And even if you don’t need them very often, the apps are worth having around just for the release notes, which are pure gold.)

Comment: A few great extra things about Citymapper here: it *always* gives you walking, cycling and "bus only" times to compare, with prices (TFL often gives fastest only even if it's only a few minutes faster than something easier or cheaper), its tube (and bus) times include average waiting times and times entering and exiting stations which some other options overlook or underestimate, and it usually gives you a few different tube options e.g. sometimes there's a slightly slower route that might be preferable because it takes quieter lines or has easier changes.